# A better way to group and count multiple columns SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count

```
I have a survey table that shows the answers that people have taken once 
a month when they enter a contest. I'm trying to find a better way to 
have the sum of  people who answer "Just Me ,My Spuse/Partner" and 
another sum of people who people who answer  Children, 0-5, 6-12,13-17

This is the table called "Survey" that is provided:
User    JustMe      Children 0-5      Children 6-12    Myspouse/partner
  5      N              N               N                  N                           
  5      N              N               N                  N
  4      N              N               N                  N
  4      N              N               N                  N
 24      N              N               N                  N
 24      N              N               N                  N
 12      N              N               N                  N
 12     Just Me         N               N              Myspousepartner           
 46     Just Me         N        Children 6-12 years   Mypousepartner
 46     Just Me         N        Children 6-12 years   Mypousepartner
```

I just hope to have table that look like this

I want my table to reflect the sum of children age group and justme/partner

```
I hope my output will be like this:
Children    JustMe/Partner
4045         1200 


  * I tried this code:
    SELECT 
    Children_13_17_years,Children_6_12_years,
    TotalSubjects= Count(*) Over (partition by Children_13_17_years),
    TotalSub= Count(*) Over (partition by Children_6_12_years)
```

Comment: Why can't you do a `SUM(CASE WHEN answer in (children answers) THEN 1 
 ELSE 0 END) as Children , SUM(CASE WHEN answer in (Just me / Spouse) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as JustMe/Partner`

Comment: Please add your expected result set.

Comment: @mkRabbani I want my table to look like this                                                                    
 Children    JustMe/Partner
 4045           1200

Comment: @WEI_DBA I did tried that method but I didn't get a count. all the values came as 0, that's why I use the over partition and I also used the select count(children 6-12,0-5,12-17)

Comment: Can you post that query you tried?

Comment: @WEI_DBA here is the code that I tried with:
SELECT Children_0_5_years,  Children_6_12_years,Children_13_17_years,Just_Me,My_spousepartner
sum(case when Children_0_5_years,  Children_6_12_years, Children_13_17_years in( Children-0-5-years,Children_6_12_years,Children_13_17_years) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as children, 
sum(case when answers in([Just Me], [My spousepartner]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as JustmePartner
FROM 2019_Audience_Report_Activity_101
   group by Children_13_17_years,Children_6_12_years,Children_0_5_years,Just_Me,My_spousepartner;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting the sum based on case statements. If the case statement is met, the sum is incremented by 1.

```
SELECT 
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Children 0-5] IS NOT NULL OR [Children 6-12] IS NOT NULL OR [Children 13-17] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '[Children]',
   SUM(CASE WHEN [JustMe] IS NOT NULL OR [Myspouse/partner] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '[JustMe/Partner]'
FROM [TableName]
```

** You may have to change the column names, aliases, and table name in the square brackets. You may also need to change the case statements to be `col != 'N'` if you have the `N` character in your database instead of null.

Comment: I do have N character in the database and when I tried using this query

   SELECT 
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Children_0_5_years] col != 'N' OR [Children_6_12_years] col != 'N' OR [Children_13_17_years] col != 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Children],
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Just_Me] col != 'N' OR [My_spousepartner] col != 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [JustMe/Partner]
 FROM [2019_Audience_Report_Activity_101]
 I got this answer An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'col'.

Comment: @cesco `[Children_0_5_years] col` should be replaced with whatever you have the column named. You don't need the word `col`. Do this for all columns in the case statements

Comment: @cesco happy to help